# Fall Trees for Fall Scene

Tags: modeling, light

Currently, I’m working on this fall scene.
[image]

I want to add trees in the background like this:
[image]
<sup>[image source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/volvob12b/45020543872/in/photolist-2bAj4cE-NXdQoi-QzCysQ-2cCWdHG-2bBkTef-2bjFEFx-efeTQ8-2bBipQb-2cCZ5dQ-QzFQEo-2bBoEpb-29WKsto-2bBipcC-2cHqFqD-2bBka2u-efeRGK-QzxoM7-2bjJM3V-212tvqa-pQVR2h-QzG7gd-pgBKBe-q16dgv-gmrWCR-q6cnxG-2cHu6Fg-qbrq6D-NXanEV-p91GVD-2bBkGYL-2uBizV-2bjFHz8-2cCXzN5-NXdLjX-QzAU1G-25FvhH5-29WKoao-QzCwch-9rb1zg-QzASLC-q4ndFN-q6wEDX-dn45Cx-6NaPSB-px9mVg-pQsnz9-mnoFGF-ahx7QF-yNksk8-efeSQK)</sup>

Also make the light look like it’s filtering thru the trees. So, my question is two-fold:

1. Is there any good tutorial on creating trees?
2. What’s the best way to create sunlight rays?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please ask only one question per post, make as many as necessary, and make sure you search existing questions before posting. Asking for tutorials or links to resources is considered off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Blender includes an add-on to generate trees - try searching for [Blender Sapling add-on Tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20sapling%20add%20on%20tutorial). This will add a new Curve option to allow you to create and configure a Sapling (there are multiple pages of settings in the Toolshelf after you Add the sapling).

For the "sunlight rays", look into [Volumetrics](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20volumetrics%20tutorials).